# python storing a dataframe as value associated with key in dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to store a dataframe as a value associated with a key in dictionary. When i print dictionary for the key,i get only column names.

```
keys=['A','B','C']

temp_list= {}
temp_list=temp_list.fromkeys(keys,list)

for key in keys:
    temp_list[key]=[]

for key in keys:
    A=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    temp_list[key].extend(A)
    #print(temp_list[key])

for key in keys:
    B=temp_list[key]
    print(B)
```

This is the output which I get is :

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I am new to python . Is it possible to store a dataframe as a value in dictionary? If it not possible , how do I create an association between the dataframe and the key ?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
keys=['a','b','c','d','e']
A=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

DICT_MAP={}
for key in keys:
    DICT_MAP[key]=pd.Series(A[key])
```

You could now map keys to DataFrame:
DICT_MAP['a']= ..SeriesDataFrame

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my keys  are different from the column names.Refer to my post. When I tried to implement your idea in my code ,i am getting an error ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 10

Comment: Modify this line:                                                                                                          
    temp_list[key].extend(A) to   temp_list[key].extend([A])   , Your original code should work. Reason is DataFrames are usually append/extend inside of a list. e.g. [df1, df2 ... and so on ]

Comment: Notice, temp_list[key].append(A) would also have worked. This is because when you have something like:   L=[ ] you cannot do, L.extend(1) but you can do L.append(2),  another option being L.extend([1])

Comment: Worked ! Thank you